# Add a watch while creating a lock using Curator Lock API

Tags: apache-curator

We have a specific case where one process will acquire a Curator lock on a key and will attach a Watch. The other process also attaches a Watch on the same key. I want the other process to be notified whenever the Lock is released: either by the process itself, or by ZooKeeper when the process is dead.

I am trying with NodeCache, but I guess NodeCache does not work  when znode type is EPHEMERAL_SEQUENTIAL. At least, my test case fails.

Comment: could you define doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem using PathChildrenCache instead of NodeCache.The curator locking API creates an EPHEMERAL_SEQUENCE mode on zk. So it was difficult to provide the exact path to NodeCache to watch upon.
The PathChiredrenCache implementation will be called back when any of the process uses the lock on the same key as they will create child nodes inside that key on zookeeper.